# Отображение сайта на андроиде

Tags: android, asp.net, разметка

Здравствуйте. Есть трехколоночный сайт на asp.net, ширина не фиксирована. Во всех браузерах на ПК с различным разрешением отображается нормально, а во всех браузерах на андроиде колонки не растягиваются на ширину картинки в шапке, хотя фиксируется только ширина боковых колонок. Есть ли какие особенности, которые нужно учитывать, чтобы сайт отображался корректно и на андроиде?

Answer (score 1):

Трехколоночный сайт? А у вас табличная или блочная верстка? Может вам надо посмотреть в сторону адаптивной верстки? Могу посоветовать посмотреть про [Мобильные приложения на ASP.NET](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/14.1.php)